# How do I cancel Toasts in a prolonged toast hack

Tags: android, kotlin, countdowntimer, android-toast

I read an article about prolonging toast messages by simply displaying a new toast before the old one dissapear.

```
fun show(context: Context?, message: String?, messageTime: Long = 60000) {
            countDownTimer(messageTime = messageTime, context = context, message = message, toastType = ToastType.REGULAR)
}

private fun countDownTimer(messageTime: Long, context: Context?, message: String?, toastType: ToastType) {
    object : CountDownTimer(messageTime, 1500) {
       override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
           val toast: Toast?
                    
           toast = Toast.makeText(context?.applicationContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        override fun onFinish() {}
    }.start()
}
```

This works. And if there are more than one `toast` showing at the same time, they are displayed interchangeably (the first is shown 1500 ms, then the second for 1500 ms, then back to the first and so on for 60 seconds or the remainder of the time).

But it does pose a major problem: Since I would like to display the toast for 60 seconds, and `onTick` is run every 1500 ms to prevent the `toast` fade to show, this means that a lot of `toast` messages will stack on one another, taxing performance (perhaps?).

This can be dealt with by canceling old `toasts`:

```
private fun countDownTimer(messageTime: Long, context: Context?, message: String?, toastType: ToastType) {
    val oldToasts = mutableListOf<Toast?>()

    object : CountDownTimer(messageTime, 1500) {
       override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
           val toast: Toast?
                    
           toast = Toast.makeText(context?.applicationContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
           toast.show()
 
        if (oldToasts.isNotEmpty()) {
            oldToasts.last().cancel()
            oldToasts.removeLast()
        }

        oldToasts.add(toast)

        override fun onFinish() {
            oldToasts.forEach { 
                it.cancel()
            }
            oldToasts.removeLast()
        }
    }.start()
}
```

Now, this works as well, removing the `toasts` so that they don't stack.

The culprint however, is when you display more than one `toast` at a time the canceling of the `toasts` becomes strange, canceling additional toasts the moment they have been displayed.

So, how do I keep multiple toasts showing nicely interchangeably like before, while at the same time canceling the ones not needed? I seem to be canceling the wrong `toast`. But I'm not sure how to implement this correctly.

Comment: Why not put a view in your own layout to handle this? If you abuse the existing Toast system, it creates an annoyance for users and may change behavior in future Android versions.

Comment: Sure! How do I manage that without using the Toast library?

Comment: Put a view in your layout that you show and hide. Or use SnackBar in your layout (instructions are in the official Android developer site).